Wdio jenkins pipeline failing, working locally
So i have a working wdio project that is just set up, i have one login test thats passing locally.
The jenkins pipeline is set by the company platform team and our internal team, its working based on jenkins dsl scripts and jobs. The issue i am having over the past week is that the jenkins pipeline build is failing constantly with one error or another.
the pipeline is quite simple and it looks like this:
@Library('jenkins-shared-library') _

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        NVM_DIR = "/home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/.nvm"
        NODE_VERSION = 'v21.7.3'
        BITBUCKET_URL = "our bitbucket url"
    }

    stages {

        stage("Integration Test checkout") {
            steps {
                git(branch: 'master',
                        credentialsId: 'bitbucket-admin',
                        url: env.BITBUCKET_URL)
            }
        }
        stage('Install and Use Node.js and Tools') {
            steps {

                script {
                    // Install nvm, slightly modified 'Manual Install' version from MVN sites.
                    // We use project directory for .nvm, not HOME (which is /root/ on Jenkins) like automatic installer does, there were problems with priviledge
                    sh 'echo "Checking out NVM to $NVM_DIR"'
                    sh 'git clone https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.git $NVM_DIR\n'

                    // Initiate nvm and install Node
                    sh '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \\. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \n' +
                            '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \\. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" \n' +
                            'nvm install $NODE_VERSION \n' +
                            'nvm use $NODE_VERSION \n' +
                            'node --version \n' +
                            'npm --version \n'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    //we need to set env. variables and run npm operations in a single sh call for sh as each sh has it has it's own session
                    sh 'export NVM_DIR="$NVM_DIR"\n' +
                            '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \\. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \n' +
                            '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \\. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" \n' +
                            'npm install \n' +
                            'npm run test \n '
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            script {
                sh 'ls -la'
                sh 'export NVM_DIR="$NVM_DIR"\n' +
                        '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \\. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" \n' +
                        '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \\. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" \n' +
                        'npx allure-commandline generate ./allure-results --clean --output ./allure-report'
                //sh 'zip -r ./test-report ./allure-report'
                //sh 'ls -la'
                //stash allowEmpty: true, includes: 'test-report.zip', name: 'testReport'
                publishHTML(target: [allowMissing         : false,
                                     alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                                     keepAll              : true,
                                     reportDir            : './allure-report',
                                     reportFiles          : 'index.html',
                                     reportName           : 'OMBO-Wdio-Report',
                                     reportTitles         : 'WebdriverIO-Test-Report'])
            }
        }
    }
}

So here is the wdio config that i set up:
import allure from 'allure-commandline'

export const config = {
    runner: 'local',
    specs: [
        '../specs/**/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
        // 'path/to/excluded/files'
    ],
    maxInstances: 10,
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            args: [
                'headless', 'disable-gpu' // '--start-fullscreen',
            ]
          }
    }],
    logLevel: 'debug',
    bail: 0,
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    services: [['chromedriver', {
            logFileName: 'wdio-chromedriver.log', // default
            outputDir: 'driver-logs', // overwrites the config.outputDir
            args: ['--port=9515', '--no-sandbox'],
            timeout: 100000
        }]
    ],
    framework: 'mocha',
    reporters: ['spec', ['allure', {
        outputDir: 'allure-results',
        disableWebdriverScreenshotReporting: false
    }],
],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },

    onComplete: function() {
        const reportError = new Error('Could not generate Allure report')
        const generation = allure(['generate', 'allure-results', '--clean'])
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const generationTimeout = setTimeout(
                () => reject(reportError),
                5000)

            generation.on('exit', function(exitCode) {
                clearTimeout(generationTimeout)

                if (exitCode !== 0) {
                    return reject(reportError)
                }

                console.log('Allure report successfully generated')
                resolve()
            })
        })
    },

    afterTest: async function (test, context, {error, result, duration, passed, retries}) {
        if (error) {
            await browser.takeScreenshot()
        }
    }
}


At first while i still didn't add: "args: ['--port=9515', '--no-sandbox']," to the services in the wdio config i was getting this jenkins error:

SevereServiceError in "onPrepare" SevereServiceError: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook SevereServiceError: Couldn't start Chromedriver: timeout Chromedriver failed to start. at ChromeDriverLauncher.onPrepare (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/wdio-chromedriver-service/build/launcher.js:91:19) at async file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:42:17 at async Promise.all (index 1) at async Launcher.run (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/launcher.js:93:13)

So i checked all unneeded services installed in wdio and deleted those, but it didn't really matter.
When i added those args above, the port and no-sandbox, i started getting a bit further with starting the the chromedriver and the session and i'm stuck with this now that i can't figure out:
+ npm run test

> test
> wdio run config/wdio.conf.js


Execution of 1 workers started at 2024-08-05T01:00:37.591Z

2024-08-05T01:00:37.600Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initializeServices: initialize service "chromedriver" as NPM package
2024-08-05T01:00:37.612Z INFO chromedriver: Initiate Chromedriver Launcher (v8.1.1)
2024-08-05T01:00:37.613Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2024-08-05T01:00:37.613Z ERROR @wdio/cli:utils: A service failed in the 'onPrepare' hook
Error: Argument "--port" already exists
    at file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/wdio-chromedriver-service/build/launcher.js:54:23
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ChromeDriverLauncher.onPrepare (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/wdio-chromedriver-service/build/launcher.js:52:19)
    at file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:42:40
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at runServiceHook (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/utils.js:39:33)
    at Launcher.run (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/cli/build/launcher.js:93:19)

Continue...
2024-08-05T01:00:37.614Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onPrepare" hook in 1ms
2024-08-05T01:00:37.614Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser driver for: chrome@stable
2024-08-05T01:00:37.619Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser binaries for: chrome@stable
2024-08-05T01:00:37.694Z INFO webdriver: Downloading Chromedriver v127.0.6533.88
2024-08-05T01:00:37.842Z INFO webdriver: Setting up chrome v127.0.6533.88
2024-08-05T01:00:38.406Z INFO webdriver: Download of Chromedriver v127.0.6533.88 was successful
2024-08-05T01:00:47.912Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2024-08-05T01:00:47.913Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onWorkerStart" hook in 0ms
2024-08-05T01:00:47.914Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,config/wdio.conf.js
2024-08-05T01:00:47.930Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Send command run to worker with cid "0-0"
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.089Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.103Z DEBUG @wdio/runner: init remote session
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.105Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initializeServices: initialize service "chromedriver" as NPM package
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - file:///specs/login_to_ombo_si1.spec.js
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.321Z DEBUG @wdio/runner: init remote session
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.322Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.718Z INFO webdriver: Setting up chrome v127.0.6533.88
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.720Z INFO webdriver: Using Chromedriver v127.0.6533.88 from cache directory /tmp
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:00:50.727Z WARN chromedriver: /tmp/chromedriver/linux-127.0.6533.88/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:01:00.741Z INFO @wdio/utils: Started Chromedriver v127.0.6533.88 with params --port=36999 --allowed-origins=* --allowed-ips=0.0.0.0 in 10246ms on port 36999
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:01:00.849Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://0.0.0.0:36999/session
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:01:00.849Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-0]   capabilities: {
[0-0]     alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', 'goog:chromeOptions': [Object] },
[0-0]     firstMatch: [ {} ]
[0-0]   },
[0-0]   desiredCapabilities: {
[0-0]     browserName: 'chrome',
[0-0]     'goog:chromeOptions': {
[0-0]       binary: '/tmp/chrome/linux-127.0.6533.88/chrome-linux64/chrome',
[0-0]       args: [Array]
[0-0]     }
[0-0]   }
[0-0] }
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:01:01.166Z ERROR webdriver: RequestError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:36999
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/got/dist/source/core/index.js:790:107)
[0-0]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:531:35)
[0-0]     at ClientRequest.emit (node:domain:488:12)
[0-0]     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:500:9)
[0-0]     at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
[0-0]     at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
[0-0]     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
[0-0]     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
[0-0]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1605:16)
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:01:01.166Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
[0-0] Unable to connect to "http://0.0.0.0:36999/", make sure browser driver is running on that address.
[0-0] It seems like the service failed to start or is rejecting any connections.
[0-0]     at startWebDriverSession (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:69:15)
[0-0]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[0-0]     at async Function.newSession (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/index.js:19:45)
[0-0]     at async remote (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js:46:22)
[0-0]     at async Runner._startSession (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:241:29)
[0-0]     at async Runner._initSession (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:207:25)
[0-0]     at async Runner.run (file:///home/jenkins/workspace/integration-tests/ombo-webdriverio-tests/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:88:19)
[0-0] 2024-08-05T01:01:01.168Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:shim: Finished to run "after" hook in 0ms
2024-08-05T01:01:01.281Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - file:///specs/login_to_ombo_si1.spec.js
2024-08-05T01:01:01.282Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2024-08-05T01:01:01.282Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onWorkerEnd" hook in 0ms
2024-08-05T01:01:01.282Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
Report successfully generated to allure-report
Allure report successfully generated
2024-08-05T01:01:02.835Z DEBUG @wdio/cli:utils: Finished to run "onComplete" hook in 1ms

Spec Files:  0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:25

I tried meddling with the args a bit, but as soon as i remove port it fails with severe service error and i tried setting up a different host other than local host but it doesen't work either.
Note i am a QA and this is more of a id say devOps topic, so i'm having trouble figuring out whats the exact issue here.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.
